# Ruby - functional approach to filtering with index

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

I have an array like this:

```
stuff = ["A", " ", "C", " ", "E", " ", "G"]
```

and I want to return an array of all the indexes where the data is a blank space say. Eg:

```
[1, 3, 5]
```

Is there a nice functional way to do this? I know there is an `each_with_index` method returning an `Enumerable`, but I couldn't figure out how to wield it with a filter.

**Edit: NVM, JUST solved it after 30 minutes of trying. Here is my method.**

```
indexes = stuff.collect.with_index { |elem, index| index if elem == " "}.
             select { |elem| not elem.nil? }
```

Comment: you could use .compact instead of the final select

Comment: search "Ruby list-comprehensions" in the archive, because that's what you need (well, at least how to emulate them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me shorten it a bit for you:

```
['A', ' ', 'C', ' ', 'E', ' ', 'G'].map.with_index { |e, i| i if e == ' ' }.compact
```

The thing is that you can use `Enumerable#compact` instead of doing a `select`. Also, I find `#map` to be the more popular term, especially when you talk about functional programming, but that's apples and oranges in the end.

Comment: this pattern (the closest Ruby has to list-comprehensions) is so common that facets has as abstraction for it: `map_select`. Other call it `comprehend`, others `compact_map`, ...

Answer (score 6):

After [many years](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5663), Ruby 2.7 ships with [`Enumerable#filter_map()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map) to make this simpler:

```rb
stuff.filter_map.with_index { |elem, index| index if elem == ' ' }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use it on multiple places i would extend the Array class with this method

```
class Array
  def index_all( val = nil )
    ary = []
    each_with_index { |x, i|
      ary.push(i) if x == val or block_given? && yield(x)
    }
    ary
  end
end

['A', ' ', 'C', ' ', 'E', ' ', 'G'].index_all(" ") #=> [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: You should prefer `||` over `or`